# How would i hide the splash screen on componentDidMount in this situation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I want to add to call SplashScreen.hide() once the screen has loaded

```
    import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
    import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
    import SignUpScreen from './src/screens/signUpScreen';
    import SignInScreen from './src/screens/signInScreen';
    import FeedScreen from './src/screens/feedScreen';
    import DonateScreen from './src/screens/donateScreen';
    import AboutScreen from './src/screens/aboutScreen';
    import AccountScreen from './src/screens/accountScreen';
    import Profile from './src/screens/accountScreens/profile';
    import PaymentCards from './src/screens/accountScreens/paymentCards';
    import Notifications from './src/screens/accountScreens/notifications';
    import CardFormScreen from './src/screens/stripeScreen';
    import ConfirmPayment from './src/components/DonateScreen/ConfirmPayment';

EStyleSheet.build();

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Feed: {
      screen: FeedScreen,
    },
    Donate: DonateScreen,
    About: AboutScreen,
    Account: AccountScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Donate',
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#6D79BF',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#4E474C',
        borderTopColor: 'transparent',
      },
    },
  }
);

const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: TabStack,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUpScreen,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    SignIn: {
      screen: SignInScreen,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    PaymentCards: {
      screen: PaymentCards,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    Notifications: {
      screen: Notifications,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    Stripe: {
      screen: CardFormScreen,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
    ConfirmPayment: {
      screen: ConfirmPayment,
      navigationOptions: { headerShown: false },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Main',
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

right now when i launch the app it just gets stuck on the spalsh screen because react-native-spalshScreen doesn’t know to hide the spalshScreen on component Did Mount

som filler text to meet stack overflow minimum text limit.
//Please ignore
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla rutrum ligula id dui mattis, luctus consectetur lacus pretium. Suspendisse porta, elit id venenatis porttitor, ipsum odio sagittis dui, sed blandit mauris justo viverra sapien. Fusce vel venenatis odio. Maecenas sit amet mattis dolor. Curabitur in feugiat ligula. Nunc sapien magna, accumsan sit amet euismod eget, vehicula eu elit. Quisque elementum ut nunc sed rhoncus. Sed euismod viverra gravida. Nulla aliquet, felis a auctor sagittis, turpis dolor vestibulum libero, vel rhoncus nunc metus sit amet libero. Suspendisse feugiat justo lorem, eget dictum justo blandit quis. Sed lacinia eros eu purus aliquet luctus. Nulla posuere efficitur lectus a ullamcorper. Nunc ut lacus varius, pellentesque ante eget, scelerisque elit.

Comment: Hi, I think you could add the `SplashScreen.hide()` in the initial screen's (seems like Main?) `componentDidMount` if it will auto navigate to that screen. It will hide after your initial screen rendered.

Comment: yes i would do that however when the user first downloads the app there directed to the signup screen

Comment: So you can add `SplashScreen.hide()` in signup screen and Main screen both.